# setting xmlHttp response type to msxml-document throws Invalid State Error in IE11

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an invalid state error when I try to set the XMLHTTPRequest object responsetype to 'ms-xml'. Does anyone know why? 
I've attached some sample code that I use for creating the object and setting the responseType property.
Thanks.

```
function getXHR() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return (new window.XMLHttpRequest());
    } else {
        return (new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
    }
}

function test() {
    this._xmlhttp = getXHR();
        try {
            this._xmlhttp.open("POST", this.uri, this.async);
            this._xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            if (this.trace > 0) {
                SoapDbg.out("SOAP URI", this.uri);
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            throw (ex);
        }

        // form SOAPMethod header

        try {
            var method_header = this._action;
            if (this.trace > 0) {
                SoapDbg.out("SOAPMethodName", method_header);
            }
            this._xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPMethodName", method_header);
        } catch (ex) {
            throw (ex);
        }

        // form SOAPAction header

        try {
            var action_header = this._action;
            if (this.trace > 0) {
                SoapDbg.out("SOAPAction", action_header);
            }
            this._xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", action_header);
        } catch (ex) {
            throw (ex);
        }

        if (this.trace > 0) {
            SoapDbg.out("SOAP Envelope", this._envelope);
        }

        // make the request

        try {
            if (this.async) {
                this._xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = this._onreadystatechange;
            }
            this._xmlhttp.send(this._envelope);
            try {
                this._xmlhttp.responseType = "msxml-document";
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("an error occured");
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to set the responseType just after open() and retry...

```
this._xmlhttp.open("POST", this.uri, this.async);
try {
    this._xmlhttp.responseType = 'msxml-document';
} catch (e) {}
...
```

It depends on the state of the XmlHttpRequest when you are setting the responseType.